# How do I base64_decode() in a JavaScript object in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, base64

If I had a JavaScript object "cat" and encoded it with btoa(), could I base64_decode() it in PHP and
access the cat's properties like color etc.? Or does PHP just see the cat as an object but does not know what kind of object it is?

JavaScript:

```
var cat = {color: "grey", name: "Spot", size: 46};
var base64cat = btoa(cat);
```

PHP:

```
$cat = base64_decode($_POST['cat']);
```

Comment: You can't encode an object like that. It's actually encoding the string `"[object Object]"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument to `btoa()` needs to be a string. If you encode an object, it's first converted to a string, so it's equivalent to

```
var base64cat = btoa("[object Object]");
```

which is not useful.

You should first seralize the object, then encode it:

```
var base64cat = btoa(JSON.stringify(cat));
```

Then to decode it in PHP you use `base64_decode()` and `json_decode()`.

```
$cat = json_decode(base64_decode($_POST['cat']));
```

But there's no real need to use base64 encoding in the first place. Just post the JSON.

Comment: Thanks, this works! Now I can access the properties like $cat->color etc.